# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in php on line 160

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

necesito ayuda con este error... mi codigo es el siguiente (alguna orientación por favor): Ya hice la correspondiente conexión a mi bd... tratao de rellenar un formulario con datos (inputs) al momento de presionar boton... ejecuta ese codigo, relacionando los (name) de los inputs ...

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$codp=$_POST['Codigox'];
$nomp=$_POST['Nombrex'];
$pat=$_POST['Appat'];
$mat=$_POST['Apmat'];
$sex=$_POST['sexox'];
$nac=$_POST['fecnacx'];
$loc=$_POST['localx'];
$zon=$_POST['zonub'];
$cal=$_POST['callex'];
$sal=$_POST['salariox'];
$nx=$_POST['numdom'];
$oc=$_POST['ocupacionx'];
$fec=$_POST['fechatrabx'];
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO 
paciente(id,codigo_pac,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,nombre,
fecha_nac,sexo,zona,calle,nro,localidad,salario_mensual,
ocupacion_actual,fecha_ingreso_a_trabajo)VALUES('$codp','$pat',
'$mat','$nomp','$nac','$sex','$zon','$cal','$nx','$loc','$sal','$oc',
'$fec')")or die(mysqli_error()) ;
echo "<h2>DATOS GUARDADOS</h2>";
}
?>
```

El error me sale en esta lineas

```
 ocupacion_actual,fecha_ingreso_a_trabajo)VALUES('$codp','$pat',
'$mat','$nomp','$nac','$sex','$zon','$cal','$nx','$loc','$sal','$oc',
'$fec')")or die(mysqli_error()) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te falta pasarle la conexion al método mysqli_query:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(TUS_PARAMETROS_DE_CONEXION_A_BASE_DE_DATOS);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO...") or die (mysqli_error()) ;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, se me olvidó poner el "include"... gracias por la respuesta montes18295 ...

Comment: @KVN20 de nada, recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta para cerrar la pregunta si has conseguido resolver el problema. Un saudo